# How do you have a list in json point to the same value?

Tags: json

I know this isn't the correct syntax, but its what I want to achieve. How would I go about accomplishing this?

```
["itemA","itemAA","itemAa"] : 10,
["itemB","itemBb","itemBB"] : 5
```

Currently, I have something like this...

```
{"items": {itemA:10}, "aliases": {"itemAA":"itemA", "itemAa":"itemA"}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have

```
["itemA","itemAA","itemAa"] : 10
```

as the keys (on the left hand-side) [always need to be strings](http://json.org/). What you can have is an array of objects, each with an array and a value

```
[
 { 
  "aliases": ["itemA","itemAA","itemAa"],
  "value": 10
 },
 {
  "aliases": ["itemB","itemBb","itemBB"],
  "value": 5
 }
]
```

Comment: Thats kinda what I thought, so I wrote up, this...

```{
    "items": [
        {
        "itemA": 10,
        "aliases":["itemA","itemAA","itemAa"]
        }
        {
        "itemB": 5,
        "aliases":["itemB","itembB","itemBb"]
        }
   ]
}```

Comment: Now I just need to re-figure this out after I rewrite that up...


`` `   def get_value(item: str):
        if item:
            item = item.replace(" ", "").lower()
            try:
                return items[aliases[item]]
            except KeyError:
                return None
        else:
            return None```

damn, the Ctrl+K and Chrome....doesnt work.

Comment: Another thing you can do is store each `alias: value` pair separately.  `"itemA": 10, "itemAA": 10`.  Then your function is just equivalent to `items.get(item)`.  You can even have the best of both worlds: store the aliases all together, so they share a value in your configuration.  But when you run the program, split them into their own `dict` entries to make lookup easier.